# AWS Cognito Federated Identity + Facebook: suggested logout flow

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

Looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html there is an example of how to code up a login using AWS Cognito + Facebook.

However, I’m unable to find examples of a logout flow. Because of the 3 parties interacting, including browser-side caching, and potentially asynchronous operations involved, it would be good to be aware of any gotchas or recommendations.

So: what’s a good way of handling logout after logging in with AWS Cognito + Facebook?